# AngularJs selecting separate fields from a directive

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, directive

I have a directive on a form group. I need to watch values of different inputs simultaneously. Lets say I have a zip code field, a country and a city field. I need to watch all of those values and ping a service when a valid value is typed(not yet submitted)

Comment: It's going to be a lot more helpful to us if you can show some of your code... without that it's very difficult to ascertain what you are trying to accomplish or how to help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement [ngChange](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) handler on your fields.